# JMeter HTTP Request: Always Sending GET Method

Tags: jmeter

All,
Every HTTP Request I make to my test REST Service is sent with the method set to GET. Tomcat rejects with a 405 - Unsupported Method. Doesn't matter what I change it to (POST, PUT, etc) Jmeter always sends a GET.

I set up the simplest possible test case by creating a Threadgroup with an HTTP Request Sampler and a View Results Tree. I send a JSON body to the REST Services which just echos back the request along with an ID. Works great with Google's REST Client UI.

Here is the result from the View Results Tree:

```
Response code: 405
Response message: Method Not Allowed

Response headers:
HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Allow: POST
Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8
Content-Language: en
Content-Length: 1045
Date: Fri, 18 Jul 2014 21:39:27 GMT
```

Here is the RequestMapping from my REST Service

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = "application/json", produces = "application/json")
```

Here are some screenshots from my results. I wonder why there are two URI's below the HTTP Request in the tree? Notice the POST request looks correct.
[image: GET Request]

[image: POST Request]

[image: Test Plan]
[image: Header Manager]

Answer (score 6):

Since the right answer is not provided yet: It's the "Follow Redirects" Option that causes this behavoir under certain circumstances.
see http://www.sqaforums.com/showflat.php?Cat=0&Number=687068&Main=675937

Answer (score 2):

Try to end the 'Path' value of HTTP Request with '/'. It has to remove the GET result in View Results Tree.

Comment: Thanks. This solved my issue, could you explain why?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. I tried everything also I read this question and all answers before find the thing that worked for me.

[image: Select Redirect Automatically]

Answer (score 0):

Content-Type should be application/json. It can not be text/html.

Set that in HTTP Header Manager. I assume you have set authentication details correctly.

Comment: Hi, I added an HTTP Header Manager with the Content-Type set as application/json and I got the same error. I set the Header Manager at the same level as the HTTP Request, and I also moved it one level higher to the Thread Group. Same error both times. I did verify that the Content-Type is being sent correctly.

Comment: Can you provide the screenshot of your test plan as well? I am testing REST API with JMeter w/o any issues.

Comment: Try this and confirm.http://java-success.blogspot.com/2013/05/jmeter-for-testing-restful-web-services.html

Comment: Ok, so instead of sending a request body, I added a nameless parameter and set the value = {"name" : "Snoopy"} like the example in the blog, and I received the same result. JMeter sent a GET instead of POST.

Comment: I also have the same issue with jmeter 5.0. It keeps sending a GET request, even though POST is specified. I too tried unchecking the "Follow Redirect" check box. Does not work still.

Answer (score 0):

We need to have three things properly set.

1. Content type which  will be application/json
2. set the endpoint correctly in the path ,which you can see in soup ui
3. Check the port number on which the api wil get run on [All this u can first check on soupui and then try running the same in jmeter